# Windows 10 Randomly Shutting Down in the middle of normal work, with message "Shutting down..."

Tags: windows, windows-10, shutdown

Starting this week, my Windows 10 has begun to randomly shut down in the middle of normal work. There are no errors or error screens. All of a sudden, the screen fades to the "Shutting down..." messages with a spinning wheel, and the PC shuts down.

I have a PC: Dell, Core i7, 16 GB RAM.

Two events have preceded this.

- I got a large Windows 10 update -- I couldn't delay any longer and did the Update, which added the "People" icon to my Windows 10 system tray, which wasn't there before.
- I bought an Insignia Wireless Keyboard+Mouse, and inserted the USB wireless device. That installed some drivers for the Insignia Keyboard/Mouse. They work properly.

***RESOLVED -- JUST AS SUSPECTED IT WAS The Insignia Wireless Keyboard+Mouse*** (My Suspicion #2). Apparently their USB device was causing overheating of some kind. I threw it a way a month ago and haven't had any issues since.

Comment: You are going have to specify which update you installed.  The People UWP was added back in I believe 1607 which is over a year old otherwise it was 1703 which is 8 months old.

Comment: @Ramhound, based upon the description of a "People" icon in the notification area, it sounds like the OP is probably referring to the [My People](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/134975/fall-creators-update-feature-focus-people) feature within the Fall Creators Update, a.k.a. version 1709... released seven weeks ago.

Comment: I'm not sure which Update # it was, but it's the icon with 2 silhouettes and when you click it you get the window that says "Your people - Pin contacts to your taskbar so you can talk to them whenever." It wasn't there before the update. Either this update or the Insignia Wireless Keyboard/Mouse is responsible for this.

Comment: What is the model of your computer? Dell is having some serious issues with heat problems on core i7 laptops. Look in the event log for why the system shutdown. See if you find an entry about Intel Dynamic Thermal Protection Framework - shutdown due to thermal event. Don’t guess. The event log tells you why the system shuts down.

Comment: The UWP application in question is a preloaded Windows 10 application similar to Calaculator.  It actually has nothing to do with your problem.  Hard to keep track of some features because they “release” them, and in the case of this application, deferred it from 1703 to 1709

Comment: @Ramhound, understood.  However, as long as we were asking the OP which update they installed, it seems prudent to be accurate regarding the time frame of their "People" app reference.

Comment: It was the Insignia Wireless Keyboard+Mouse after all. Their USB device ma have been causing overheating. I threw it out last month and haven't had issues since.